# Is it possible to copy file in tfs 2010 build process template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, workflow

I can see that there is a copyDirectory activity, but no copyFile activity. Is there any way to copy only one file from directory?
Or maybe there is a way to delete a single file from directory?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no FileCopy activity. You can 1) develop your own custom activiy or 2) use the  [InvokeMethod](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vi-VN/tfsbuild/thread/0b86cd0b-ff98-4ca0-86f6-1da89cb47d6e).

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to write your own activity. Try to use [TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com) instead.
There is a RoboCopy workflow activity you can use to copy files. there are a lot of other very useful activities like E-mail activity, ...

Follow [this nice guide](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template&referringTitle=Documentation) to modify DefaultTemplate workflow or any workflow inside BuildProcessTemplates folder.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I already had those extensions installed

Answer (score 2):

I would use the InvokeProcess activity and call the xcopy command in there with the correct arguments. See for an example: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-15-Fail-a-build-based-on-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application.aspx